# Maximum edge weight from one node A to node B

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, disjoint-union

Given a connected undirected graph having **N** nodes (1 <= **N** <= 2 * 10^5) and **N-1** edges. Let's define a function **F(a,b)**, where **F(a, b)** is equal to the maximum edge weight in the path from *a* to *b*. How do we find the sum of the **F(a, b)** for all *a*, *b* such that **1** <= *a*, *b* <= **N** (mod 10^9 + 7)

Example figure

[image]

F(a, b) is equal to the maximum edge weight in the path from a to b.

F(1, 2) = 2

F(1, 3) = 2

F(1, 4) = 4

F(1, 5) = 4

F(2, 3) = 1

F(2, 4) = 4

F(2, 5) = 4

F(3, 4) = 4

F(3, 5) = 4

F(4, 5) = 3

Sum of F over all pairs is equal to 32.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I actually have a n^2 solution, in which i ran dfs from each node, thereby calculating the answer for every pair of node. Cannot figure out an optimized solution.

Comment: Please show your algorithm.  We may be able to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a variant of Kruskal's MST algorithm for this (Kruskal is sort edges by increasing weight, greedily insert the ones that don't make a cycle with the aid of a disjoint set data structure). Initialize a running sum to zero; whenever we merge a disjoint set of size S1 (this information is available as a byproduct of a disjoint set data structure that does union by size) with a disjoint set of size S2 via an edge of weight w, add S1*S2*w to the sum mod 10^9 + 7.

Comment: In particular, this works because every time we add an edge, it's necessarily the max-weight edge connecting nodes from opposite sides, because we're adding edges in order of increasing weight.