# Find maximal weight edge between two nodes in an undirected acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, undirected-graph

We have a graph with **N** nodes and **N-1** bidirectional edges(each edge has some weight **w**).
Now we have to answer **q** number of queries. Each query gives two nodes **u** and **v** and maximum allowed cost at any edge **x**. If the individual edge weights of all edges between path from **u** to **v** is less than or equal to **x**, then we print **Yes** otherwise we print **No**.

The constraints are as follows:
1 ≤ **N,q** ≤ 10^6
1 ≤ **w,x** ≤ 10^9

I have tried the brute force solution but it gives TLE. I know I have to do some preprocessing but can't get my head over it.
I found a similar question here but no one clearly addressed that part.
[Maximum edge weight from one node A to node B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293481/maximum-edge-weight-from-one-node-a-to-node-b).
You can visit the link for better explanation of the problem.

Comment: You can solve this with *Dijkstra's algorithm*, since each node has at most one edge, this will result in an *O(n)* algorithm here. While performing Dijkstra's algorithm, you can "optimize" the graph meanwhile, such that work done in the first query, can be exploited in the second.

Comment: Please explain that optimisation in an answer. I'm too naive to understand as my knowledge is limited to standard Dijkstra algorithm only.

Comment: this *is* the standard Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand how I can optimize the graph to exploit in further query. Please at least provide the pseudocode or some explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about computer science, not programming.

Comment: @DanielMann This question was asked in a 2 hour programming contest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easilly solved using Union Find (also known as Diesjoint Set Union, if never heard about it you can look up implementation [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html)) data structure in O(n*log(n) + q*log(q))

1. Read all queries and store them in some array structure (keeping query info u v x and index of query)
2. Sort all queries by weight
3. Sort all edges by weight
4. Go throught all queries, if needed merge all still unmerged edges with weight <= query weight
5. If nodes u and v are in same connected component (Find(u)==Find(v)) then answer for this querie is Yes else no
6. Print answers in needed order